# Geonear is not working - mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geo

I have following sample mongodb document in the collection `offers`.

#### Collection : Offers

```
 {
   "countryCode" : "LU",
   "geoLocation" : [ 
         {
            "lat" : 49.8914114000000026,
            "lng" : 6.0950994999999999
         }
    ]
 },
 {
   "countryCode" : "DE",
   "geoLocation" : [ 
         {
            "lat" : 50.8218536999999984,
            "lng" : 9.0202151000000015
         }
    ]
 }
```

#### Requirement:

Fetch the document based on the geolocation which is around 50km radius

#### What I have tried:

```
db.getCollection('offers').aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: [6.0950994999999999, 49.8914114000000026],
            distanceField: "geoLocation",
            maxDistance: 50000, //50 km radius
        }
    }
]);
```

#### Problem:

It is fetching all the documents instead of searching around 50km.

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Legacy coordinate pairs do not return distances in meters, but in radians instead. Your maxDistance therefore much larger than 50km. See [Calculate Distances with Spherical Geometry](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/)

But also consider the actual distance being used here:

```js
db.getCollection('offers').aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: [6.0950994999999999, 49.8914114000000026],
            distanceField: "distance"
    }
]);
```

Returns:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dc0f4b6f07ad5d3ec3b6d0"),
    "countryCode" : "DE",
    "geoLocation" : [
            {
                    "lat" : 50.8218537,
                    "lng" : 9.020215100000001
            }
    ],
    "distance" : 60.588259822017925
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dc0f4b6f07ad5d3ec3b6cf"),
    "countryCode" : "LU",
    "geoLocation" : [
            {
                    "lat" : 49.8914114,
                    "lng" : 6.0950995
            }
    ],
    "distance" : 61.93733827090219
}
```

As the "distanceField" is meant to be the field that reports the projected distance from the queried point.

So the start point is that your documents are ot valid for geoSpatial queries. Fix them like this:

First drop all indexes:

```js
db.offers.dropIndexes();
```

Then fix the fields:

```js
var bulk = db.offers.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.offers.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { 
  //printjson(doc);

  var tmp = {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [doc.geoLocation[0].lng,doc.geoLocation[0].lat]
  };
  doc.geoLocation = tmp;
  printjson(doc);

  bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
    "$set": { "geoLocation": doc.geoLocation }
  });
  count++;

  if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
    bulk.execute();
    bulk = db.offers.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  }
});
```

Now the data is represented in a correct GeoJSON format:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dc14856f07ad5d3ec3b6d1"),
    "countryCode" : "LU",
    "geoLocation" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    6.0950995,
                    49.8914114
            ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dc14856f07ad5d3ec3b6d2"),
    "countryCode" : "DE",
    "geoLocation" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    9.020215100000001,
                    50.8218537
            ]
    }
}
```

Now create an index as 2dsphere:

```js
db.offers.createIndex({ "geoLocation": "2dsphere" })
```

Now you are ready to query:

```js
db.offers.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [6.0950994999999999, 49.8914114000000026]
      },
      "distanceField": "distance",
      "spherical": true,
      "maxDistance": 50000
    }}
])
```

Which returns the one document that is "near", or in fact 0 distance:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55dc14856f07ad5d3ec3b6d1"),
    "countryCode" : "LU",
    "geoLocation" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    6.0950995,
                    49.8914114
            ]
    },
    "distance" : 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, But above query is not returning any resultset

Comment: @karthick.k See the information above. You are also using `$geoNear` incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, But following query is not working with maxDistance,  db.getCollection('offers').aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: [6.0950994999999999, 49.8914114000000026],
            distanceField: "distance",maxDistance: 50 / 6378.1
    }
]);

Comment: @karthick.k Well there are lots of things wrong here, and not just one. The answer now is a full guide to fixing all your problems.

Comment: FYI this answer also works with a nested structure. Thanks Blakes.